# Why won't my menu buttons open a Link? CSS, jQuery or HTML issue?

Tags: jquery, css

Why won't my main menu buttons open a URL link once you click it? The **main green buttons** not the drop down. Is it a CSS, jQuery or HTML noob mistake?
 Is it possible to have both the drop down and for the main button to be click able?

**Click on the 'Contact' button on the actual website layout**/
http://www.restoredestates.com/

The Code that won't work:

```
      <ul>
        <li class="button"><a href="contact.html" target="_blank" class="green">Contact<span></span></a></li>
```

**Oddly it works for the jsfiddle code:**   http://jsfiddle.net/VCUgrad08/rapat/1/embedded/result/

It doesn't work on the actual website. :( I need the button that says "contact" to actually link to "contact.html" (not the drop down, the link up there now is only temporary)

Disclaimer: I was in a hurry with coding this website.

Comment: It does in the jsfiddle for some odd reason but not the actual website. Go to the website link please. Thank you for your interest.

Comment: Tried clicking the actual website and it seems to be working fine

Comment: The 'Contact' button is supposed to link to the contact.html form page.

 <ul>
        <li class="button"><a href="contact.html" target="_blank" class="green">Contact<span></span></a></li>

Comment: can't you give your java script code that handle the left menu?

Comment: Sure. Here's the url to javascript: http://www.restoredestates.com/js/jquery.easing.1.3.js

The js should be in the jsfiddle. I'm really don't know what's going on

Comment: that is because in your script.js you have written e.preventDefault(); on $('li.button a').click event

Comment: Thank you so much Priyank. Can I delete it? How do I fix it? I'm a beginner.

Comment: no dont delete it, otherwise it would affect your js code

Comment: can you call a function on cotact.html link ? then i can give you solution

Comment: I don't know. Maybe if I delete the drop down menu only for the 'Contact' green button it won't be an issue if I do delete that one line? :/ eek confused lol

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this code. hope it will work

```
<ul>
    <li class="button">
    <a class="green contact" target="_blank" href="contact.html">
```

js

```
 $("contact").click(function(){
        window.open("http://www.restoredestates.com/contact.html", "_blank");
    });
```

Comment: Thank you Priyank. It now works the way I need it to work. http://restoredestates.com/. The Drop Down jquery funtion and the Click Open BOTH work for the menu. 'Services' still drops down and 'Home' and 'Contact' are both clickable to link to each other. THANK YOU THANK YOU THANK YOU :D